# What is the point of the sep="" at the end?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python.org, What's New in Python 3? it gives this example of the print function:

```
print("There are <", 2**32, "> possibilities!", sep="")
```

which produces:

```
There are <4294967296> possibilities!
```

What is the point of the `sep=""` at the end of the print function? Surely the meaning is obvious without it.

Comment: Did you consider [reading the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)?

Comment: Just got stackoverflow confused with google temporarily!

Comment: You don't need Google if you read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *default* value for `sep` is a space. By setting it to an *empty* value you print without spaces between the 3 inputs.

You could easily have tried this without the `sep` argument to see the difference:

```
>>> print("There are <", 2**32, "> possibilities!", sep="")
There are <4294967296> possibilities!
>>> print("There are <", 2**32, "> possibilities!")
There are < 4294967296 > possibilities!
```

Note the spaces between the `<`, the outcome of the `2**32` expression and the `>`.

The *point* then is to control how `print()` outputs the given arguments, something that was not possible in Python 2 where `print` is a statement.

Perhaps a different example would illustrate this better:

```
>>> sample = ['foo', 42, 'bar', 81.0]
>>> print(*sample, sep='\n')
foo
42
bar
81.0
```

By setting the separator to a *newline character* I made `print()` write all arguments out on separate lines instead.

Comment: Am assuming the asterisk means 'contents of'.

Comment: @mistermarko: `*args` expands the `args` to become separate arguments to the `print()` call.

Comment: *Sigh*. Please do *not* vote on answers because you dislike the question. If you find my answer unhelpful or otherwise *wrong*, I'd love to receive feedback on that in a comment, so I can improve my answer. But take out your frustration with a question out by closing or voting down the question, not the answers.

Comment: There's a bug in the system. I upvoted it when I meant to accept it (which I have now done) so I then immediately downvoted it. The system should change so ups and downs from the same IP address cancel and are not counted. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @mistermarko: I've edited the post unlocking any votes on it; you are allowed to both upvote and accept, btw, the two actions are not mutually exclusive. :-) You can *undo* a vote by clicking the same arrow again.